# NullPointerException : Attempt to read from field 'com.android.volley.Cache$Entry com.android.volley.Response.cacheEntry

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

Am getting JSONArray from external API using Android Volley. My code is below

```
StringRequest jq = new StringRequest("http://api.example.com/json/States", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String jsonArray) {
            try {
                Log.d("Success", jsonArray.toString());
            } catch (Exception je) {
                je.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.d("Error", volleyError.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    AppController a = AppController.getInstance();
    Log.d("Queue", "Add");
    a.addToRequestQueue(jq);
```

Am keep getting same error below

> NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.android.volley.Cache$Entry com.android.volley.Response.cacheEntry' on a null object reference
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.android.volley.Cache$Entry com.android.volley.Response.cacheEntry' on a null object reference
>               at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:126)

I tried various methods. But still am having same problem. I Cant understand where is the issue. Help to fix this

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: Not exactly. now I changed my code into new JsonArrayRequest from StringRequest and its working.

Answer (score 8):

You are not parsing the response . You are returning only null and not parsing cache headers. After parsing the response you can return the response with cache headers parsing like this :

```
return Response.success(networkResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(networkResponse));
```

Return this in parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) method